# Help me to translate this: "살림 만렙 안뜰살뜰 깔끔쟁이 우렁이와 바쁜 일상 속에..."

Tags: translation

I found it on a manhwa synopsis:
살림 만렙 안뜰살뜰 깔끔쟁이 우렁이와 바쁜 일상 속에 지치고 외로운 승하의 상큼달콤한 힐링 동거 로맨스

I'm using papago but the translation is so bad. When i tried to figure it out by translating each word and combine it, i don't know which phrase come first

Edit: here's the machine translation from papago
"Salim Mannreb's Ancestral Garden Cloth and the Sassy Healing Cohabitation Romance of a weary and lonely monk in a busy life."
And here's from google translate
"Salim mabreu courtyard Salad tidy snarling and tired in busy everyday life Lonely heavenly sweetheart living together Together romance"

Comment: please post the bad translation as well, someone might be able to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

A cool-sweet healing cohabitation romance of Ureong-i, the best housekeeping neat freak, and Seungha, the weary loner in his hectic routine.

### Long Answer

Removing all the modifiers in the sentence, you have

> 우렁이와 승하의 로맨스

So there are two characters 우렁이 and 승하, and there making a romance. 우렁이 means a freshwater snail, and there is a folklore about a snail doing house chores for a farmer. (References in Korean [#1](http://culturecontent.com/content/contentView.do?content_id=cp052111610001) [#2](https://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=569589&cid=46643&categoryId=46643))

And let's take a closer look at the modifiers for each of 우렁이, 승하, and 로맨스.

#### 살림 만렙 알뜰살뜰 깔끔쟁이 우렁이

**[살림](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/0b281ae8cb6a418b95df3c9acd19c4ac)** means housekeeping, and 만렙 is something like a maestro or top-level. Compound of Chinese character 만(萬; ten thousand, or figuratively a very big number) and 렙(from English 'level'), it means the highest possible level of a video game.

EDIT: I just noticed that 만 for 만렙 might actually be 만([滿](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BB%BF); full, packed), thus "full level, complete level" in a video game. I don't have any academic backup for either etymological theory.

**[알뜰살뜰](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/db8e7ab56d7c422ea86943ba89a43196)** means one is thrifty, sparing, and good at 살림.

**[깔끔쟁이](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/a1899e6fdfea4eab85fb4531cec1adac)** refers to a person who is more or less obsessed to keeping things clean and tidy. It may have a derogatory nuance.

Thus, Ureong-i, the best housekeeping neat freak.

#### 바쁜 일상 속에 지치고 외로운 승하

I think this part is plain textbook Korean. Seungha, the weary loner in his hectic routine.

#### 상큼달콤한 힐링 동거 로맨스

**상큼달콤한** is a compound of [상큼하다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/de9f1410b6d64f0ab5145fe04f87d872) and [달콤하다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/870d81988c394d42a5fc3fc8e126b902). 상큼하다 means cool and refreshing like a lemonade or a fresh strawberry. 달콤하다 means sweet and tasty like chocolate or a lollipop. Both are primarily used to describe flavor or scent, but here it is understandably used to describe a "로맨스(romance)."

**힐링** is from English 'healing'. In a contemporary Korean context, it is used to describe a media production (movie, TV series, anime, webtoon, etc.) or to describe an experience (having a cup of coffee at your favorite coffee shop, seeing your friend's lovely pet dog, spending a weekend at a luxury hotel, etc.) that soothes, comforts, and mentally or emotionally "heals" you. I don't think there's an English equivalent to describe this kind of specific meaning, is there?

**[동거](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/49d4162afd884d559c2b831aacf82f30)** means cohabitation, with a strong implication of a not married couple, but it doesn't always *have* to be a sexual relationship (although it is also strongly implied by the word). It can also be used in a situation of two or more non-sexually related friends. (Like those in the Big Bang Theory or whatever.)

**로맨스** is from English "romance", and I think shares most of its meaning with the English word. It can refer to a specific emotion, a literary genre dealing with such emotion, or a piece of fiction of such genre.

Thus, a cool-sweet healing cohabitation romance. It's a romantic story, where the two characters live together, and the overall tone will be comfortable and soothing, as opposed to a comedy or a crime thriller.

Answer (score 1):

살림 housekeeping 만렙 best level

안뜰살뜰 is a mimetic word representing 'extremely frugal'

깔끔쟁이 a neat and tidy man

우렁이 a pond snail

@There is a Korean traditional story telling 'a pond snail-wife
talented at a housekeeping'

바쁜 일상 속에 지치고 외로운 승하 tired and lonely 승하 in busy
routine.

상큼달콤 is a mimetic word representing 'refreshing and sweet'

힐링 동거 로맨스 healing cohabitation romance.

Refreshing and sweet healing cohabitation romance **of**
housekeeping-best-level, extremely frugal, neat and tidy
 pond-snail-man **and** busy-routine tired and lonely 승하.